# How to reuses page--front.html.twig for multiple pages

Tags: theming, 8

I created a page--front.html.twig which allows me to create a distinctive front page.

How would I go about reusing this page to create a *landing page*, a page with an identical layout the front page has?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`, and you can suggest the template file used for those land pages.

I assume you are doing it from a theme; if you are doing it from a module, you can implement either `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)` like for themes or `hook_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables)`.

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($your_condition) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__front';
  }
}
```

The code you write for `$your_condition` depends from how you check which pages are your land pages. The following are some useful snippets you could need.

- To get the internal path for the current page

  ```
  $internal_path = Url::fromRoute('<current>')->getInternalPath();
  ```

  Alternatively, the current path can be obtained with `\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()` (Drupal core uses both of those)
- To get the node being viewed

  ```
  if (!empty($variables['elements']['#node'])) {
    $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
    // Get the content type.
    // $bundle = $node->bundle();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` with the page HOOK. You should be able to add what ever login you need to add your suggestions to:

```
/**
 * Implements of hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  ...
}
```

If you do this in your theme you should be the last to enter your override suggestion and it should work great.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the other suggestions are good, but incomplete. If you already have the needed theme suggestions and you only need to include the code from one template into another, then the only thing you need to do is this:

```
{% include 'page--front.html.twig' %}
```

In fact, if I was you, I would keep the theme suggestions separate (as opposed to setting all of them to page--front) and just create "template pieces" that can be later joined together are reused using [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#including-other-templates) or [template inheritence](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#template-inheritance). This allows you to reuse repetitive templates, but have the flexibility to do adapt them to specific needs.